# How to make an ajax call that return values to the controller succesfully?

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, api

I already asked a similar question some days ago,but now I have a problem. I can't return succesfully the values I want to the controller. Let's say I have this controller

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/ricercaUtente", method = {RequestMethod.POST,RequestMethod.PUT}, consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE}, produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
public ResponseEntity<BaseAjaxResponse<List<UtenteDto>>> ricercaUtente( @RequestParam (required=false) String nome,                                                         @RequestParam (required=false) String cognome){
```

return List;
    }

This is my html..

```
    <form id="myForm" action="/rest/ricercaUtente">
            <input type="text" id="nome" name="nome">
            <input type="text" id="cognome" name="cognome">
            <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit">
        </form>
```

and this is my ajax

```
    $(function() {
console.log( "DOM pagina di esempio caricato" );

$("#myForm").submit( function(evt){
    //Stoppo il comportamento di default del submit
    evt.preventDefault();
    ricercaUtente();
} );

    });


    function ricercaUtente(){
var ricarcaUtenteUrl = $("#ricercaUtenteUrl").val();
nome = $("#nome").val();
cognome = $("#cognome").val();
$.ajax({
    url : ricarcaUtenteUrl,
    dataType : 'json',
    contentType : 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    type : 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify({nome:nome,cognome:cognome}),//tried this and                   {nome: nome, cognome: cognome}

    beforeSend : function(){
        var busyImgUrl = $("#busyImgUrl").val();
        $.blockUI({ message: '<h1><img src="'+busyImgUrl+'" /></h1>' });
    },
    complete   : function(){
        $.unblockUI();
    },
    success : function(data) {
        var codiceEsito = data.operationResultCode;
        var datiContatto = new Object();
        if (codiceEsito == 200) {
            datiContatto.utente = data.payload;
        } else{
            datiContatto.errore=true;
        }

    },
    error : function(data) {
        var datiContatto = new Object();
        datiContatto.errore=true;
    }
});}
```

I tried launching tomcat in debug mode but values "nome" and "cognome" are always null...Does anyone know what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you checked the usual suspects?  `console.log($("#nome").length)` / `data: { nome:nome, cognome:cognome}` (ie without stringify) / stripped down (without the beforeSend/complete sections / do you get an error?  What is the error if there is one (use all 4 params on `error:` as last is the message) / Is it actually hitting the controller (implied only, not stated)?  What does the browser network tab say it's sending?  Not sure about [spring] but try with just `method = {RequestMethod.POST }`

Comment: You are sending JSON not request parameters, so yes the call to the controller will fail.

Comment: Yes It is hitting the controller,I checked in debug mode,also as you suggested I tried consolelogging the values and I get what I input in the form but in the backend I get null values(both from debugging and the log of the query,which is as follows:

select blabla from user blabla
where
        utente0_."NOME"=? 
        and utente0_."COGNOME"=?)